# mvc 5 - User.IsInRole("Admin") times out

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Within my ~/Home/Index page, I want to show a link if the user is in a specific role, like this :

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    if (Context.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Users", "Index", "User")
    }
}
```

I get past `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`, because I was able to connect to my membership database and authenticate when I logged in.

So connecting to that database doesn't seem to be an issue.

Who would these 2 time out?

`(Context.User.IsInRole("Admin"))` in my view

and `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` in my controller.

Comment: Did you look at the error message? More than likely the database hosting the membership is not responding as a result of being down, a bad internet connection and or route, or a concurrency issue.

Comment: Can you post the whole error?

Comment: This is what comes up in Firefox - A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)              which as we all know means it can't connect to the database.  But I was able to connect when I logged in and authenticated.

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the SQL server instance? `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = true` only shows that you've successfully created a cookie.

Comment: Yes. I log in (even after changing the password to verify I can connect) and immediately go to this page that does the IsInRole check.

Comment: That error message is very specific: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified.aspx

Comment: Answered here -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24259549/user-isinrole-throwing-a-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error